# Teradata SQL - find the last match in a column then return value from row below

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table like below: I've order the table by Time, ID. I want to find the last Event 44 for each ID and get the value below it.

Table:

```
ID    Time    Event
A   00:10:00    11
A   00:10:11    44
A   00:10:13    22
A   00:10:00    11
A   00:10:11    44
A   00:10:13    33
A   00:10:13    22
B   01:10:00    ?
B   01:10:11    44
B   01:10:13    11
B   01:10:00    44
B   01:10:11    ?
B   01:10:13    22
...   ...         ...
```

Desired result:

```
ID    Time    Event
A   00:10:13    33
B   01:10:13    22
... ... ...
```

Have tried different ways, but still struggling... Any help would be appreciated. Many Thanks!

Comment: (1) Why are you not returning `B   01:10:11    ?`?  (2) SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so what is the ordering of the rows?

Comment: Hi GL, (1) I need to return one row only for each ID - the row next to the last ' Event 44' ; (2) I ordered this table by ID, Time.

Comment: What about rows with NULL events? Seems like you want to ignore them and get the next row with a NOT NULL event?

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, yes, only not null event... I should have filtered table with 'where event <> '' '.... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a column that actually represents the ordering *and* that you really do want the next row, here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when event = 44 then next_ordercol end) over (partition by id order by ordercol) as event44_next
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(ordercol) over (partition by id order by ordercol) as next_ordercol
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where ordercol = event44_next;
```

I always forget that Teradata doesn't implement `lead()` and `lag()`.  I really don't get it.  Here is one method:

```
      from (select t.*,
                   max(ordercol) over (partition by id order by ordercol rows between 1 following and 1 following) as next_ordercol
            from t
           ) t
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. is 'lead' a function in TD v15? **lead(ordercol) over (partition by id order by ordercol) as next_ordercol'**  the 'ordercol'  is my Event column? @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

This will result in a single STAT FUNCTION step in Explain:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE event IS NOT NULL
QUALIFY
    -- previous event was 44 
        Min(event) -- LEAD
        Over (PARTITION BY id
              ORDER BY "time" DESC 
              ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND 1 Following) = 44 
    AND
    -- only return rows when there was no previous 44 event
        Count(CASE WHEN event = '44' THEN 1 end)
        Over (PARTITION BY id
              ORDER BY "time" DESC ROWS Unbounded Preceding) = 0
```

e.g.

```
ID       TIME   Event    Lead  Count
 A   00:11:14      22      33      0
 A   00:11:13      33      44      0
 A   00:11:11      44      11      1
 A   00:11:00      11      22      1
 A   00:10:13      22      44      1
 A   00:10:11      44      11      2
```

If you run TD16+ there's finally support for LAG/LEAD instead of the MIN rewrite:

```
Lead(event)
Over (PARTITION BY id
      ORDER BY "time" DESC)
```

Could be rewritten without the WHERE event IS NOT NULL using LAST_VALUE (or LEAD) plus IGNORE NULLS option, but this will result in two STAT FUNCTION step in Explain.

Comment: Hi thank you for the details, helps a lot as I am new to TD. unfortunately, my TD is v15... is your way more efficient than the answer above? I am pulling data from more than 20 million rows.... :(

Comment: 20 million rows is not a big table in Teradata. The MIN version works fine with TD15, LEAD is just shorter syntax. And it should be more efficient, because Gordon's answer wil need two STAT FUNCTION steps, simply Explain both queries.

Comment: lol, forgive my naivety here, scared by 20 million rows... that's great comment, will try this out. Many thanks again.